# Update Customer Custom field QuickBooks Desktop

Tags: desktop, quickbooks

I am using consolibyte lib to integrate QuickBook Desktop with PHP app. 
I need to update customer's custom field using PHP library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom fields are called `DataExt` elements in QuickBooks desktop.

You can refer to the QuickBooks OSR for exact XML syntax on what to send to QuickBooks:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

We also have lots of examples on our website of doing what you're trying to do:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

Specifically, this example may be helpful:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Customer_with_Custom_Fields

Copy/pasted from that link:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">

        <CustomerAddRq requestID="Q3VzdG9tZXJBZGR8MTExMTIxMjE=">
            <CustomerAdd>
                <Name>Keith Palmer Jr.</Name>
                ...
            </CustomerAdd>
        </CustomerAddRq>

        <DataExtModRq>
            <DataExtMod>
                <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                <DataExtName>CustomerNumber</DataExtName>
                <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
                <ListObjRef>
                        <FullName>Keith Palmer Jr.</FullName>
                </ListObjRef>
                <DataExtValue>1234</DataExtValue>
            </DataExtMod>
        </DataExtModRq>

    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

You should be able to plop XML like that in to the examples included in the quick-start guide of this PHP library and be on your way.

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

If you have trouble, you should post the XML you're sending to QuickBooks, and the error message or XML that you get back from QuickBooks. Code is helpful too.

Comment: Thank You! Keith. it worked for me. I am wondering how I can update custom fields of multiple customers in single request.

Comment: Pretty much the same way that's indicated above. Just add another `<DataExtModRq>` node for each additional custom field you want to update.